# Key events in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I implemented a code for adding items like circle, line etc on click of a button in graphics View. With the help of signals and slots I was able to add the items mutiple times on click of a button for example When I pushed the Line button, I can add the line mutiple number of times and there was no need to push the button again and for destroying this I used keyevents i.e When I push the ESC that event should end. But when I do so the application crashes and window closes. Following is the code snippet. Please do check what is going wrong

mainwindow.h

```
    #include "line.h"



    namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
    }

    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();


        QPainter *painter;
        line *item1;



    private slots:
        void drawLine();
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
    void MainWindow::drawLine(){
        ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
        item1 = new line;
        scene->addItem(item1);
        qDebug() << "Line Created";
        connect(item1, SIGNAL(DrawFinished()), this, SLOT(drawLine()));
    }


    void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
    {
    if(event->key() == Qt::ESC) {
      connect(item1, SIGNAL(DrawFinished(),SLOT(drawLine()));
      scene->remove(item1);

}
```

Comment: This won't compile. There are missing `}` braces, and `)` parentheses. Paste the relevant fragments of the actual code you're running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
itemN->deleteLater();
```

This will let Qt handle signals gracefully and delete the object when it is safe to do so.